# Doubt while proving that an irreducible matrix lie algebra representation implies an irreducible matrix lie group representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a connected matrix Lie group with Lie algebra $g$. Let $\Pi$ be a representation of $G$ acting on $V$ a finite dimensional vector space, and $\pi$ the associated representation of $g$. There is a theorem that says that in this case, $\Pi$ is irreducible iff $\pi$ is irreducible.

I am trying to understand the proof. I have understood the part where we show that an irreducible $\Pi$ implies an irreducible $\pi$. Nonetheless there is something I don't see in the proof of the converse.

The proof goes like this. Assume that $\pi$ is irreducible. Let $W$ be an invariant subspace of $V$. Then $W$ is invariant under $\Pi(e^{tX})$ where $t$ is a real number, and $X$ is an element of the Lie algebra $g$. The next claim is that this implies that $W$ is also invariant under
$$\pi(X)=\frac{d}{dt}\Pi(e^{tX})\bigg|_{t=0}.$$
I don't see why. So, why does the fact that $W$ is invariant under $\Pi(e^{tX})$ make it also invariant under $\pi(X)=\frac{d}{dt}\Pi(e^{tX})\bigg|_{t=0}$?

Comment: Not sure if your V is finite dimensional or a topological vector space or what, but...Let $p$ be the projection to the orthogonal (or any) compliment of $W$.  Then $p(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \Pi(e^{tX})w)=  \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}p\circ \Pi(e^{tX})w=0$

Comment: $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space. I am a physics student so my math knowledge is a bit on the paleolithic yet and I don't know what the orthogonal compliment of a vector space is. Could you please state your answers without resorting to that concept?

Comment: @Scardenalli, you probably do know what the orthogonal complement of a subspace is: it's the set of vectors perpendicular to the subspace. More formally, suppose $V$ is a vector space equipped with an inner product (a gadget that acts like the dot product in Euclidean space, and thus allows you to talk about perpendicularity). A vector $v \in V$ is defined to be in the orthogonal complement $W^\perp$ of a subspace $W \subset V$ if (and only if) $v$ is orthogonal (that is, perpendicular) to every vector in $W$.

Comment: @Vectornaut ok. But then why so the derivative and $p$ commute?

Comment: @Timkinsella, do you mind if I write up your comment as an answer?

Comment: I think the point that you are missing is that a linear subspace of a finite dimensional vector space is automatically closed in the sense of topoligy. Hence the derivative, which is a limit of difference quotients lies again in the subspace. Otherwise put, if you have a curve that lies in a subspace, its velocity in each point lies in the same subspace (think of curves in the plane inside of $\mathbb R^3$).

Comment: @Vectornaut not at all!

Comment: @Scardenalli they commute by the chain rule, since p is linear.