# Irreducible Representations of a Lie Algebra and the Exponential Map

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Having found an irreducible representation of a Lie Algebra, we get the representation of the Lie group using the exponential map. Is the representation of the group then irreducible too? If so, how do I see that.

PS: I found a post that asked the same question (alongside three other questions), but I could not quite understand how the given answer was sufficient to prove the statement:
[From irreducible representations of the Lorentz algebra to irreducible representations of the Lorentz group](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/357183/)

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: You are probably right. My question came up from a physical background, but still, it's pure mathematics. Shall I delete it from this forum?

Answer (score 1):

Let $h:{\cal G}\rightarrow U$ be a representation of Lie algebra. Suppose that the representation of the $1$-connected group associated to the Lie algebra ${\cal G}$ is reducible. This implies that there exists a subset $V$ invariant by $G$. We can define $\rho:G\rightarrow Gl(V)$ the restriction of the previous representation which induces a representation $Lie(\rho):{\cal G}\rightarrow gl(V)$ which is the restriction of the previous representation $h$, which is nor irreducible contradiction.

Comment: The way you constructed the reductio ad absurdum requires the following statement: From the fact, that $V$ is $G$-invariant follows, that $V$ is also ${\cal G}$-invariant (using the $Lie(\rho)$ representation), am I right? If so, how can this be shown?

Comment: Edit: I think, I found the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451111/doubt-while-proving-that-an-irreducible-matrix-lie-algebra-representation-implie