# Irreducible representation of Lie group vs. of the underlying Lie Algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Every morphism of Lie groups $\phi: G_1 \to G_2$
defines a morphism $\phi_*: \mathfrak{g}_1 \to
\mathfrak{g}_2$. This induces the map

$$ \operatorname{Hom}(G_1, G_2) \to
\operatorname{Hom}(\mathfrak{g}_1, \mathfrak{g}_2)  $$

$$  \phi \mapsto \phi_* $$

For $G_2:= \text{GL}_n(V)$ (respc.
$\mathfrak{g}_2= \mathfrak{gl}_n(V)$) the map $\phi$
(resp. $\phi_*$) is a representation of Lie group
resp underlying Lie-algebra on the vector space $V$.
It is known that for $G_1$ connected, simply connected the
map $ \operatorname{Hom}(G_1, G_2) \to
\operatorname{Hom}(\mathfrak{g}_1, \mathfrak{g}_2)  $
is bijective (cp. Kirilov's notes Introduction to Lie algebras).

Question: Can we conclude in this case for
connected, simply connected $G_1$ that
$\phi: G_1 \to \text{GL}_n(V)$ is *irreducible*
iff $\phi_*: \mathfrak{g}_1 \to \mathfrak{gl}_n(V)$ is
irreducible? Of not, are there any sufficient conditions known?

In detail, for connected, simply connected $G_1$ the inverse
map to $\phi_*$ is given by exponentiation
$\text{exp}(\phi_*)$ where $\text{exp}: \mathfrak{g}_1 \to 
G_1$.

More, generally, assume that $G_1$ is non neccessarily
simply connected, but the representation
$\lambda: \mathfrak{g}_1 \to \mathfrak{gl}_n(V)$
lifts to a Lie-group representation
$\Lambda: G_1 \to \text{GL}_n(V)$. If we assume,
that $\lambda$ is irreducible, can we conclude that
$\Lambda$ is irreducible too? If not, under which conditions
this becomes true?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4190025/irreducible-representations-of-a-lie-algebra-and-the-exponential-map).

Comment: Yes, this is true and we only need to assume that $G_1$ is connected. The argument proceeds by showing that a subspace is $G_1$-invariant iff it's $\mathfrak{g}_1$-invariant, using the fact that the image of the exponential map generates $G_1$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I see. The proof which uses for exponential map the property $\frac{d}{dt} exp(tv)=v$ as "special" feature or exponential map. I'm just wondering if it can by deduced with methods from pure category theory, or is this some "very special feature" of Lie groups & algebras? Let's try to express it in terms of category theory: Say we have a functor $F: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$, which is bijective on Hom sets, ie $Hom(A, A')= Hom(F(A), F(A'))$. Then, is it true that $\phi: A \to A'$ factors trough a $C \subset A'$ iff $F(\phi):F(A) \to F(A')$ factors through $F(C)$?

Comment: The implication "$\phi$ factors over $C$ implies $F(\phi)$ factors over $F(C)$ is obvious by functoriality. Is the other direction also true? (To relate it to business with representations as special case: set $C= GL(V') \times GL(V'') \subset GL(V)$ with $V' \oplus V''=V$)

Comment: If you want to restrict to the simply connected case, then yes, you can deduce it from the fact that we have an equivalence of categories between representations of $G_1$ and representations of $\mathfrak{g}_1$ in the simply connected case, but this argument requires stronger tools than the argument I'm proposing, and the argument I'm proposing is also more general.